# reactjs useEffect cleanup function after fetching data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, use-effect

I've read some good practices in reactjs using useEffect. I have a situation which I separated my function to fetch the data and call it on the useEffect hook. How could I make some cleanup functions in this situation. ?

I've seen some useEffect cleanup like these:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let isActive = true;

  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      if (isActive) {
        setTodo(data);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

  return () => {
    isActive = false;
  };
}, []);
```

From the example above, the fetch function is inside with useEffect, now how can I perform some cleanup if something like this situation:

```
const getTodos = async () => {        
        try {
            const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
            const todos = await response.json();
            if(todos) {
                setTodos(todos);
            }
        }catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }    

useEffect(() => {
        let mountedTodos = true;
        getTodos();

        return () => {
            mountedTodos = false;
        }
    },[])
```

Comment: You can keep the `isActive` in global scope or define the `getTodos` inside the useEffect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be handled in multiple ways.

- You could have `mountedTodos` as a global variable outside the component.
- You could defined `mountedTodos` as an object and pass it to `getTodos` function.

However, I suggest you to use an [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController)

```
const getTodos = async (signal) => {        
    try {
        const response = await fetch(/*url*/, { signal });
            const todos = await response.json();
            if(!signal.aborted) {
                setTodos(todos);
            }
        }catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }    

useEffect(() => {
   const abortController = new AbortController();
   getTodos(abortController.signal);

   return () => abortController.abort();
},[])
```

Note: You should add `getTodos` in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook and to avoid infinite loop of state update and re-render, wrap `getTodos` in `useCallback` hook.

Comment: Btw, the first option that you have suggested, I don't want to apply it because when dealing with alot of cleanup functions, I may also declared some global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Create a flushTodos function and call it in return statement of useEffect and in that function just update your state of todos to blank array.

```
return () => {
  flushTodos();
}
```

And other option is: I hope you are using todos as a state so you can directly update the state in return statement of useEffect like this:

```
return () => {
  setTodos([]);
}
```

Comment: What happens when the response is received _after_ `flushTodos` function has been called and component has unmounted? `getTodos` function will update the state of an unmounted component.